# How can i remove the borders arround a floorplan image

Tags: matlab

I would like to fill the building area to get outer boundary of entire building, instead it is filling whole area in the border.
Input image [image: Input]

I=imread('http://porterdrivecampus.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/shared/images/som/plans/3172_floorplan_1st.gif');
    BVO=bwarea(imfill(I,'holes'));
    TotPix =numel(I);

```
if BVO>(TotPix*0.95)
 BW = imfill(I1,[1 1],8); %filling inner hole
 B=imclearborder(BW);
 nI1=imfill(B,'holes');
else
 nI1=imfill(nI101,'holes');  
end

figure;
imshow(nI1);
```

Desired Output [image: Desired Output]

Comment: can you post what output(rough) you want?

Comment: I am getting outer boundary (Rectangle) of floorplan instead of building

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    clc,clear

[I,map] = imread('1kuuZ.gif');
I1 = ind2rgb(I,map);                % convert indixed image to rgb
I2 = im2bw(I1,graythresh(I1)+0.3);  % binarize
% figure, imshow(I2), title('binarized image');
[L,n] = bwlabel(I2);
% figure, imshow(L,rand(n,3)), title('labeled image');
prop = regionprops(L,'Area');       % find area of each label
area = cat(1,prop.Area);
[~,ix] = max(area);                 % find biggest area
I3 = ~(L==ix);                      % extract biggest area
% figure, imshow(I3), title('biggest area image');
I4 = bwareaopen(I3,500);            % clear area (remove small regions)
% figure, imshow(I4), title('biggest area (cleared) image');
[L,n] = bwlabel(I4);
prop = regionprops(L,'Area');       % find background
area = cat(1,prop.Area);
I5 = L==ix;                         % extract biggest area (floor)
% figure, imshow(I5), title('floor area image');
I6 = edge(I5);
% figure, imshow(I5), title('floor area final image');

% comparing of original and final images
I7 = imdilate(I6,ones(5));
I8 = I2 & ~I7;
Ic = cat(3,I7*0,I8,I7);
figure, imshow(Ic), title('comparison image');
```

Process

[image]